# Is it possible to have a reactive isVerified call for Meteor users?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Using the Meteor Accounts package, each users' email has a property of `verified`. I'd like to check this from the client and reactively update the dom. In short, I've got a template that lists all users that belong to a group and I want to mark those users that have responded to the sendVerification() email that was sent to them.

Imagine:

```
<template name="users">
  {{#each allusers}}
    {{> user}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="user">
  <span>{{name}}</span>
  <span class="{{isVerified}}">Verified</span?
</template>
```

With:

```
Template.user.helpers({
  isVerified: function(){
    var user = this;
    // return true if this user is verified (has replied to verification email)
    Meteor.call('checkVerification', user, function(err, verified){
      if (verified) return 'active';
      else return '';
    });
  }
});
```

The problem with the helper above is that Meteor.call is not reactive so the template is already rendered before I get a response. The other problem is the Meteor.users collection is (or should be) only available on the server and I can't allow the client to subscribe to the entire collection.

So, apart from redrawing the dom using jquery when I get a response, is there a good way to hook this together to make a useful `isVerified()` function?

Comment: Where is the helper that provides the 'user' template's `this`?  Just thinking that your user information is coming from the server already the obvious thing to do is to also set an 'isVerified' field at that time.

Comment: @user728291 I had the same thought but the trouble is allUsers is reading from an array stored in a separate `Group` object. I'd either have to maintain a separate `verified` property in that object, not ideal, or check each user's state inside the publish statement - which seems expensive.

Comment: 'Expensive' is a relative term.  Either approach requires the same data.  You are just creating extra traffic between client and server as well as splitting a single database call into many.  Code is easier to follow with a single publish too.

Answer (score 0):

Just update a Session value when you get the callback.

```
Template.user.isVerified = function(){
  return Session.get("verified");
}

function checkVerified() {
  var user = this;
  // return true if this user is verified (has replied to verification email)
  Meteor.call('checkVerification', user, function(err, verified){
    if (verified) Session.set("verified", true);
  });
}
```

Then just call `checkVerified` whenever you want. I recommend not doing that in a template helper, as you'll be hitting the server every time the template renders and executes the helper, but somewhere in your code where an action happens. For instance, after the user has completed sign up. Or when they load the page the next time. etc.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean I'd need a session variable for each user (or at least each member of the group)? I should be clear, I'm not talking about the currently logged in user, but all of them. I guess I could key the session var by email but that doesn't feel like the right way to use sessions.

Comment: In that case, you should probably set a `.isVerified` property on the user's record in the server, and make sure that information is published to the client. If you then use it in the template, Meteor will make sure the template is rerendered reactively.

Comment: Yes, of course. I can publish all users that are members of the group to the client and filter the publish function so it only returns email and a verified flag. Secure and efficient. Thank you.